# Cant update meteor collection

Tags: mongodb, collections, meteor

I'm new to Meteor, and I can't figure out why this happens? I have a collection called `gameCol` which I'm trying to update. There is only one single document in the collection which matches the criteria. When I'm updating like this:

```
gameCol.update({started:true}, {$set:{started:false}});
```

Meteor throws

```
Meteor.Error.prototype = new Error; at line 144 livedata_common.js
```

If I'm updating like this:

```
var status = gameCol.findOne({started:true});
gameCol.update({_id:status._id}, {$set:{started:false}});
```

everything works as expected.

This seems a bit odd to me, and I can't really find anything that explains it either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citation form the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#update):

> Untrusted code [= js on the client] can only modify a single document at once, specified by its _id. The modification is allowed only after checking any applicable allow and deny rules.

This is for safety reasons ([explainations here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr&fromgroups=#!searchin/meteor-talk/security/meteor-talk/qUa3clv4g5E/N7F8IaAX5AgJ)). So you need to use your second piece of code that works.

Comment: Thank you! That explains it.